# Questions about Ruby koans about_classes.rb

Tags: ruby, methods

Here're the codes from about_classes.rb. I'm not very sure about why the answers are `[ ]` and `[:@name]`

```
class Dog2
def set_name(a_name)
  @name = a_name
end

def test_instance_variables_can_be_set_by_assigning_to_them
    fido = Dog2.new
    assert_equal [ ], fido.instance_variables 
#In this case, fido doesn't have any instance_variables, 
because it is assigned to a new "Dog2" Hash/class which has none methods?

    fido.set_name("Fido")
    assert_equal [:@name], fido.instance_variables 
#In this case, fido has an instance_variable, 
because it uses the set_name methods inherited from "Dog2" classes?
end

assert_raise(SyntaxError) do
  eval "fido.@name"
  # NOTE: Using eval because the above line is a syntax error.
end
#So Eval here means that if the above returns "fido.@name", give it a SyntaxError?
```

I added some comments under those 2 cases, see if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `Dog2` is, but if it doesn't have any instance variables, it doesn't have any instance variables at the time you're calling it. Whatever `Dog2` is, it's creating instance variables when you call `set_xxx` on it, where the instance variable is named after whatever `xxx` is, from the looks of it. Ruby creates instance variables the first time they're accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first `assert_equal` is called, the `Dog2` instance (`fido`) has no instance variables, because none were defined in the initializer or in any other way.

When `set_name` is called the `@name` instance variable gets set, so by the time the second `assert_equal` is called the `fido` instance **does** have an instance variable, one, `@name`, so the `fido.instance_variables` method returns an array with that one symbol.

#### Update

In response to the questions you pose in the comments in your code sample:

No, your first two comments are not accurate. It's not because it has no methods, it's because it has no instance variables.  The `fido` instance **does** have a method, the `set_name` method.

Your second comment is not accurate because there's no inheritance going on here, `fido` is an instance of `Dog2` and so once the `set_name` method has been called it has an instance variable, because `@name` is initialized in that `set_name` method.

Your final comment/question about the `eval` is just because if the authors had actually written just `fido.@name` then the code itself would have failed to run, they wanted it to run but display that **if** you'd written `fido.@name` in your code then Ruby would have exited and refused to run your code because of that syntax error.

#### Another Update

After another question from the OP I wanted to just add, although `@name` exists inside the `set_name` method, the point really of this example is to show that in Ruby until `set_name` is called that `@name` variable doesn't exist yet. In other languages you would define all the instance variables up front, so they'd always exist for any instantiated object of that class.

Ruby is a much more dynamic language and so until that `@name = a_name` line of code is actually executed, the `@name` variable doesn't exist, so is not returned in `fido.instance_variables`

This would also be true even if that method is called, but that `@name = a_name` line isn't executed, so, eg.

```
class Dog2
  def set_name a_name
    if false
      @name = a_name
    end
  end
end

fido = Dog2.new
fido.set_name "Fido"

fido.instance_variables # => []
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Smathy, it sounds more clear to me. I don't entirely understand why `@name` is not the instance variable of `fido`. Because `fido` has the method `set_name`, so it should also have the instance variable `@name` right?

Comment: @Penny 1) `fido` is a new `Dog2`, whatever that is. I'm not sure why you keep saying "hash" all over. 2) Because `instance_variables` returns an array of instance variable symbols; one of the instance variables is `@name`, which as a symbol, is `:@name`.

Comment: @smathy We don't actually know it has a `set_name` method. Oh, now we do--it could also have been a `method_missing` implementation. But the question was edited and I browsed away for a bit :/

Comment: @DaveNewton it's also part of the [ruby koans](http://rubykoans.com/) - maybe you missed Penny mentioning that.

Comment: Thank you @Smathy, it sounds more clear to me. I don't entirely understand why `@name` is not the instance variable of `fido` in the case of `fido = dog2.new`. Because `fido` has the method `set_name`, so it should also have the instance variable `@name` right?

Comment: @Penny the point is that in Ruby, until `set_name` is called, the `@name` instance variable hasn't been defined, so doesn't exist in `instance_variables`

Comment: @Smathy, so it means that I can write `assert_equal [:@name], fido.set_name.instance_variables

Comment: No because `set_name` doesn't return the `fido` instance, so your `instance_variables` call there isn't on `fido` it's on the return of `set_name`

Comment: @smathy No, I didn't, but questions need to be complete without sending people looking for context.

Comment: Good answer, but I find the updates and flipping between the answer and comments is confusing. It may be OK for the OP, but not for those, like me, who read the questions and answers at a later time. I suggest that if a question is posted in a comment, you either answer with a comment or edit your answer to deal with it. Moreover, unlike edits to questions, I see no reason for edits to answers to include a mention that it is an edit. It's better, imo, to edit silently and provide an integrated answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My first update is referring to the comments in the code sample of the question, not the comments here, I've made that clearer.  My second update references that there was a comment but is actually a standalone clarification. In other words, you don't need to jump back and forth between these comments in order to understand my answer, only between question and my answer. So I'll leave it as it is.